# minimizing distance of the linear image of a vector of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

let $A \in M_ {m,n} (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ and $Q \in M_n (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ , is there a way to find $X \in M_n (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ minimizing
$||AX+Q||$ where $||vector||$ mean the sum of the coordinate of the vector considered as $\mathbb{R}$ element ?

Comment: I think there may be a typo in your problem, what is $R$? Do you mean $Q$, but then $AX$ is a vector, but $AX+Q$ does not make sense as the dimensions of the matrices aren't necessarily the same.

Comment: ah yeah thanks i changed that :)

Comment: Presumably $X$ also has components from $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. Anyway, Í very much doubt that a general efficient algorithm for finding the minimizing $X$ exists. After all, this is equivalent to the nearest codeword problem for binary linear block codes. Good algorithms exist for some codes. That is, for some specific matrices $A$. I suspect that some general results exist about the computational complexity of the task, but I cannot cite one at the moment.

Comment: i was thinking considering element like R/2Z find a distance and try to approach little by little, but i dont know if it will work. Like the distance could be d(a,b) the minimal positive representant of b-a but its not even symmetric....